# Tkinter Canvas Object Transparency Option?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there is a transparency option for tkinter canvas objects.

i.e

```
canvas.create_oval(x1, x2, y1, y2, transparency...)
```

If not, is there a non-pythonic way of doing the same thing?

Comment: The closest thing you can get to transparency with arbitrary Canvas shapes is to set a stipple pattern - but that's really a grid of completely opaque/completely transparent pixels, which is probably not quite the effect that you're looking for.  Also, it's not fully supported on all platforms - ovals can't be stippled on Windows, apparently it doesn't work at all on current Macs.

Comment: No, there is no transparency option.

Comment: so I just mix the colours to a decently accurate ratio?

Comment: Maybe you can use tif images with no background (transparent) instead of creating canvas objects?

Comment: Relevant [tkinter+transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+tkinter+transparency)

Comment: Relevant but doesn't help much - looking for object properties not widgets